# Union and intersection; Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If  the cardinality of $(A\cup B)$ is equal to the cardinality of $A$ plus $1$, then what can you say about set $B$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I understand that that union of two sets is the set of elements which are in either set, but not sure what it is clearing asking. A is a union of B.

Comment: It is asking you, given that the number of elements in the union of $A$ and $B$ is one greater than the number of elements in $A$, what does that mean about $B$? Try finding a few examples of sets $A$ and $B$ that satisfy this property, you should be able to see a pattern.

Comment: @user94991, by $n$, do you mean the cardinality of the set right?

Comment: Yes that is what it is asking.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

If $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$, then we know that $|A|+|B|$ is the cardinality of $A\cup B$ when the sets are *disjoint*. Generally, for finite sets $A$ and $B$, $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.

If $|A\cup B|=|A|+1$, what can you conclude on $B$?